# Retrieving an image from rich text field?

Tags: apex, visualforce, case, pageblocktable, richtextarea

Have a rich text field called - `snapshot__c` which has image in it. This field is inside custom object called `obj__c`.

`obj__c` has another field `case__c` using lookup in it.

On a Vf page, I'm selecting a case and need to display the image (`snapshot__c`). I am able to fire the query, but the image isn't just getting displayed. Instead getting something weird. Image for reference:

[image]

Query in controller:

```
con = [select snapshot__c from obj__c WHERE Case__c =: ex.case__c];
```

VF pageblock:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!con}" style="width:1200px;" var="c" rendered="{!if(showPB==true,true,false)}" border="2" title="Some Name">
    <apex:column value="{!c.snapshot__c}" style="width:500px;" rendered="false" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Any alternative for `apex:pageBlockTable` and/or `apex:column` ? Can I just use `div` and how? What am I doing wrong? Pls help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rich fields are stored as HTML in Salesforce, so to retrieve your image, you will have to parse the text and get the image from there. Luckily this is a fairly simple task to do.

Once queried, the field will look like this in the variable:

[image]

What you want is what is in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag. You can just copy the tag, or get the link and remake it in your page (using a repeat attribute or something).

Here's a sample code on how you would do this (I used a Developer Edition organization with a object from Trailhead):

```
Campsite__c camp = [SELECT Id, RichField__c FROM Campsite__c LIMIT 1];

System.debug('Rich field:');
System.debug(camp.RichField__c);

String firstSubString = camp.RichField__c.substringBetween('<img', 'img>');
System.debug('First substring: ' + firstSubString);

String secondSubString = firstSubString.substringBetween('src="', '"');
System.debug('Second substring: ' + secondSubString);

String link = secondSubString.replace('amp;', '');
System.debug('Link: ' + link);
```

Comment: How simple is it? On the fly, how do I retrieve that scr code?

Comment: Query for the field in the controller, and use the method `substringBetween(open, close)` from the String class. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_substringBetween_2

Comment: Read about it. So, in my case you meant to say, I will have to add the `<img src` as open and `<img>` as the 2 parameters?

Comment: No, because you have the `alt` tag too. I would use `<img` and `img>` and then get the URL separately.

Comment: Could you pls provide any example that would help. Still stuck...

Comment: Added sample code on my post. Check it out.

Comment: Charm! I used this in a way I wanted and it worked! Thanks again mate.

Comment: On which module did you find this at the Trailhead?

Comment: I didn't find the answer on Trailhead. I used an object that is used on the lessons (because I was too lazy to create one just to simulate your issue). If you are interested though, the trail I got this object from is the Developer Beginner.

Comment: Nice solutions, resolved my issues as well

Comment: how can I pass the link Variable in Image tag on VF. It Shows src unkown to me.
I received the extracted src and did this on VF ''<!apex:image alt="" url="{!link}" id="image"/>

Comment: @Nehal use a simple HTML image tag instead of the Visualforce one.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira, still not working. Tried this as well <img src="{!link}" alt="Location"/>

Comment: @Nehal perhaps your link is broken or you don't have access to it then? Because that's how the HTML is stored in Salesforce as well (look at the image in my post).

Comment: @RenatoOliveira I checked the url, there is a veritcal bar in my url which is replaced by &#124; . I guess this might be creating issues and & is changed to &amp

Comment: @RenatoOliveira, can you help me on this. How to replace  &#124; by | . I have tried using replace function, but it is not working it shows the same url

Comment: Might want to open a different question for that. Your issue now seems to be related to encoding instead of retrieving the image URL. I'm not sure I can help without seeing how the URL is formed or how you are retrieving it.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code,

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!con}" style="width:1200px;" var="c" rendered="{!if(showPB==true,true,false)}" border="2" title="Some Name">
<apex:column>
  <apex:facet name="header">Snapshot</apex:facet>
  <apex:outputText value="{!c.snapshot__c}" escape="false"/>
</apex:column></apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: I did try this, gave error as - SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: obj__c .snapshot__c

Comment: oh that shouldn't happen. You are actually querying snapshot__c field in the query right?

Comment: Added `rendered="false"` after `escape="false"` which gave the same output like the one in question.

Comment: Yes, I re-checked the query and its right. Getting same as @Renato displayed it. Can we skip column tag and use any other? Plus, why the `apex:outputText ` as the image would not be the text, but some image which is in RTF.

Comment: `img=img.substringBetween('src="', '"');
img=img.unescapeHtml4();` 

What I did is the same way, but used different parameters. But had the issues with decoding the `&amp;` character in the URL. The last line `unescapeHtml4()` actually resolved the issue