# Accessing ContentReference records via api

Tags: standard-objects, chatter-answers

I'm working on an app to migrate chatter answer question records into another object.
Using apex code I have a process that can map question fields, but haven't found a way of mapping/migrating inline images.
Question's body  is a Rich Text Area field and inline image are stored as contentReference leaving an `img` tag on the body of the question. The `img` URL has a reference to the question Id and also to a contentReference Id.
Has anyone been able to access the image file other than via the URL itself?
Ideally I'd use another API to migrate images apart from the apex logic I have, but haven't found a way.

Comment: When I try to access the content object directly by  http://instance.salesforce.com/content_reference_id I get a .

Comment: do you mean like this : https: //xx.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P36000002gIvb

Comment: the prefix is 0EM.
In the question body content the image is stored like this :
image <img alt="leloo" src="https://c.naXX.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=906o0000000XXXX&amp;feoid=Body&amp;refid=0EMo0000000XXXX"></img>
When I try to access the content object directly by  http://instance.salesforce.com/content_reference_id I get an "Insufficient Privileges" message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this wonderful [article](http://salesforcefox.blogspot.com/2014/08/migrate-images-in-rich-text-area-field.html):

You can access base64 body of your image by initizalising PageReference with your URL, and then taking content of it.
After that you can store this e.g. in your documents.

```
String container = 'https://c.na30.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?'+
    'eid=0033600000DwnWB&feoid=00N3600000ISvb4&refid=0EM36000000HZEt';
PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(container);

string strFolderId = '00l36000000aPPB';

Document doc = new Document();
doc.Name = 'pic1';
doc.Type = 'png';
doc.Body = pageRef.getContent();
doc.FolderId = strFolderId;
doc.Description = 'chatterPostId';

insert doc;
```

You can create trigger, which can transfer rtaImage to document image and replace it with document url src. You can send callout with image body...

Comment: Ilya, I ended up implementing a workaround based on you suggestion, moved the content migration to a separate batch process and used allowCallouts. I can convert up to 100 images per run, but we can live with that. Sorry the late update, and thanks